# Gauge Function Properties

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Currently I'm reading a paper titled "Fixed Point Theorems for Multivalued $\alpha$-Function" and I have a problem on proofing one of its function's properties.

Let $J \subseteq [0,\infty)$ that contains 0. A function $\psi : J \rightarrow J$ is gauge function of order $r \geq 1$ if
(i) $\psi(\lambda t) \leq \lambda^r \psi(t)$, for all $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $t\in J$, and
(ii) $\psi(t) < t$, for all $t \neq 0$.

How can I proof this?

If $\phi : J \rightarrow J$ is gauge function of order $r > 1$ and there exist a nondecreasing and non-negative function $\varphi : J\rightarrow J$ such that $\phi(t) = t \varphi(t)$, for all $t \in J$, then show that $\varphi(0) = 0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as $\varphi$ is non-decreasing, and non-negative, it is continuous, and $\varphi(t) \ge 0$

Now, we have $$\phi(\lambda t) = \lambda t\varphi(\lambda t)$$
and 
\begin{align}
\phi(\lambda t) &\le \lambda^r \phi(t) \\
&= \lambda^rt\varphi(t)
\end{align}

So, $$0\le \varphi(\lambda t)\le \lambda^{r-1}\varphi(t)$$

Taking the limit $\lambda \to 0$, as $r>0$, $\lambda^{r-1} \to 0$.  Thus, $\lim_{\lambda\to 0} \varphi(\lambda t) =0$

As $\varphi$ is continuous, $\lim_{\lambda\to 0} \varphi(\lambda t) = \varphi(0)$. So, the result is proved.

Comment: How can $\varphi$ be continuous? As we only know that $\varphi$ is non-decreasing and non-negative